# Python PyAD setting multiple workstations during creation of user

Tags: python, active-directory, python-3.7, pyad

Trying to add multiple workstations using pyad.  I am able to set a single workstation, but not multiple workstations.

```
from pyad import aduser

ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn(
  "ou=someplace, DC=domain, DC=com")
new_user=pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(
      "test02", ou, password="password123",
       optional_attributes= 
       {'userWorkstations':
        'computer1','computer2'})
```

I've also tried using ldap3 with the same result. It completes the operation, but when looking in Active Directory, it only sets the first workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at the ADSI editor in Active Directory, I found my mistake.

```
'userWorkstations' :"computer1,computer2"
```

my mistake was that I had a space after the comma.
Thank-you for everyone's assistance.